# dojo/dijit popup menus do not disappear after losing focus

Tags: drop-down-menu, menu, dojo

I am using dojo 1.9.6 and finding widgets that use classes with nodes `dijitPopup/dijitMenuPopup` on rare occurrence do not disappear after the mouse loses focus of that menu. The menu will stay on the page until the browser page is refreshed. On some occasions, multiple menus would get stuck in succession and all will remain until the page was refreshed.

After some investigation I found the style `display:none` is not applied after losing focus, but the `dijitMenuPassive` class was applied. I am not sure if there is an error with the `onblur` function not triggered correctly. There is no console error or log output that appears relevant when this happens. Observed the most (if not exclusively in) IE 10

My questions is more about is this a documented or noticed issue among dojo menu users? Is there any suggestion in how to fix it? I have witnessed this in many applications where dojo is used (and in multiple versions of dojo), but it is a rare occurrence and finding a pattern where it occurs is difficult. Thanks for any insight!

Example of issue:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/loiWh.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a guess, but you might be running into a somewhat rare but infamous bug in IE 9-10:  clicking on a link that does not navigate anywhere but also does not cancel its click event confuses the event system and causes the wrong listeners to fire for the wrong events.  Note that this includes `javascript:` links (which generally shouldn't need to be used anyway).

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/802397/ie9-ie10-events-can-be-sent-to-the-wrong-listeners

You may need to do some hunting through your application to determine if this is your issue, but if it is, you'll want to call `preventDefault` in a `click` handler on the affected links, or find some other means of doing what you're currently doing with them.

Comment: Upon further investigation, this does appear to be the issue. Unfortunately I do not control this part of the application that uses empty links, but I have reported this as a bug and hopefully it will be fixed soon. Thank you!